# STM32H7: Why do I need a barrier instruction in this loop?

Tags: stm32, memory-barriers

This simple loop copies bytes from an STM32H742 FDCAN Rx fifo to normal RAM. Without the DSB the loop simply halts. I could not find out which state the core is in because I can't start debugger for unknown reason. Alternative to the DSB instruction a nop loop (I tried 500 nops) also did the job.
It is hard to find out details because any additional code like outputing values to a UART also fixes the issue. But in the final version I want it as short as possible of course.
Any ideas why the barrier is needed?
(Using STMCubeIDE, compiler is set to optimization -Ofast)

```
uint8_t * block_data;
char * buf_ptr_ch;
uint32_t block_byte_idx;
uint32_t byte_cnt_total;
// initialising the variables esp making buf_ptr_ch point into FDCAN memory
while (byte_cnt_total > 0)
{
 block_data [block_byte_idx] = *buf_ptr_ch;
 block_byte_idx++;
 byte_cnt_total--;
 buf_ptr_ch++;
 __DSB ();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I would say, the only way to properly answer this is to look at disassembly. The loop is small enough for it not to be too hard. Also, don't use "nop" instructions to waste cycles. The processor is free to optimize them away even if they're in the code and jump straight to the next instruction, according to ARM documentation. So you have actually no way to tell how many of those NOPs were executed and how many were simply ignored. You can always use MOV R0, R0. And you should definitely solve debugger problem first. At some point you will need it anyway.

Comment: If you don't use the values then the compiler knows it doesn't need to calculate them.  Adding the __NOP macro adds some inline assembler, but this is just a hacky way of confusing the compiler to not know whether you really use the value or not, so do something (anything) with the values.  Also, `-Ofast` is just code for "please break my code".  Try `-O3`.

Comment: Is there a reason to copy bytes, rather than, say, `uint32_t`s? Or have you tried `memcpy()`?

Comment: @Ilya thanks for the nop-hint, I thought it is always mov R0, R0 but there realy is a nop instruction

Comment: @pmacfarlane buf_ptr_ch does not start 4 aligned the first byte has a special meaning and is fetched before the loop

Comment: @Tom V I would like to learn what you mean with -Ofast = "please break my code". I found that -Ofast ist just a bit more than -O3. Why is -O3 better?

Comment: @Ilya Can you explain why you want to look at disassembly? My understanding of barriers is that they take effect on things happening after the code was fetched eg in the pipeline, cache or so. So the assembler code, when assuming it runs in the given sequence, will always look fine. Am I wrong with this?

Comment: In theory, this code is supposed to run correctly without memory barriers. We want to see what CPU really does there instruction by instruction that somehow requires barrier or a pause. We don't know what's going on yet, but I think in this situation disassembly would be a good place to start. It could be a caching issue, but we need to see actual instructions to see at what moment memory reads and writes happen. All of this definitely looks weird, I think disassembly could shed some light.

Comment: Also, how did you even come up with trying a barrier? It's not exactly the first idea that comes to mind when your loop doesn't work.

Comment: `-O3` means compile the program as fast as possible while remaining correct.  `-Ofast` means standard compliance is no longer required, so compile even faster even if the result is not correct.

Comment: I will be off next week and would like to continue the week after. Hope you will still be around